# Results of Names doesn't match probability

Tags: java

I'm trying to write this program that picks between 3 names at random
and when a name is chosen it decreases the probability of the name appearing again by 10% every time the name pops up.

The problem is when I'm changing all the names in the for loops to one name, I get 90% of the name I changed everything into and 10% of one of the other 2 names.

```
String [] arr = new String[30];

int i; int b; int g;

for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    arr[i] = "moshe";
}

for (b = 9; b < 20; b++)
{
    arr[b] = "Nir";
}

for (g = 22; g < 29; g++)
{
    arr[g] = "Yoad";
}

double letsdomath = Math.random()*arr.length; // Exp: return the no. 10 / 30 letsdomath = 10

if (letsdomath < 11) // if i get moshe
{
    for (i = 0; i <= letsdomath - 1; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = "Nir"; // Originally it would be Moshe here
        arr[i + 1] = "Nir";
    }
}

if (letsdomath > 11 && letsdomath < 21) // if i get nir
{
    for (b = 0; b <= letsdomath -1; b++)
    {
        arr[b] = "Nir";
        arr[b + 1] = "Nir"; // Originally it would be Yoad here
    }
}

if (letsdomath > 21 && letsdomath < 30) // if i get yoad
{
    for (g = 0; g <= letsdomath -1; g++)
    {
        arr[g] = "Nir"; // Originally it would be Yoad here
        arr[29] = "Nir"; // Originally it would be Moshe here
    }
}
System.out.println(arr[(int) letsdomath]);
```

Expected results:
To get the name Nir to pop up every time

Actual results:
The name Nir pops up 90%~ of the time, and the name Yoad pops up 10%~ the time.

Comment: I believe your problem is that you are comparing a `double` with an `int`. What happens if `letsdomath` is, for example, 11.2 ? It's greater than 11 (eleven), right? Now what does `(int) letsdomath` give you? (Hint: 11 [eleven]).

Comment: i'm casting int, it fixes it @Abra

Answer (score 1):

Let's revisit your description of what you want to do: why not implement each of those things you talk about as "things we can do", and then run "as many iterations as we like" that simply run through those in order?

For example, let's start with the basics:

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.Math;

public class Test  {
  String[] names;
  int len;
  double[] probabilities, thresholds;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
  }

  public Test() {
    init();
    int steps = 5;
    for (int i=0; i<steps; i++) {
      // do the thing!
    }
  }

  public void init() {
    // set up a probability distribution
    names = new String[]{"name1", "name2", "name3"};
    len = names.length;
    thresholds = new double[len];
    probabilities = new double[len];
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
      probabilities[i] = 1./len;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, we make sure there's a way to look up probability thresholds: if the probabilities are [0.4, 0.3, 0.3] then we want thresholds [0, 0.4, 0.7] so that we can easily work with the fact that a random number >= 0 but < 0.4 should resolve to index 0, a number >= 0.4 but < 0.7 should resolve to index 1, etc:

```
// turns [0.3, 0.4, 0.3] into [0, 0.3, 0.7]
public void setThresholds() {
  double tally = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
      thresholds[i] = tally;
      tally += probabilities[i];
  }
}
```

Then, let's define the function that rebalances the probabilities, based on the name index we pick:

```
// turns [0.4, 0.3, 0.3] with pos=0 into [0.36, 0.32, 0.32]
public void updateProbabilities(int namePos) {
  double sprinkle = (probabilities[namePos] * 0.1) / (len - 1.);
  probabilities[namePos] *= 0.9;
  for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if (i == namePos) continue;
    probabilities[i] += sprinkle;
  }
}
```

Right, so with that all set up, we can now update `public Test()` to run a million and one update passes by relying on these functions working as we intend (which you should, of course, verify):

```
  public Test() {
    init();

    int steps = 5;

    for (int i=0; i<steps; i++) {
      setThresholds();
      double randomValue = Math.random();

      // find the associated name by finding the index of
      // the threshold that is higher than our random value.
      int namePos = findIndex(randomValue);
      if (namePos == -1) {
        namePos = names.length;
      }
      namePos--;

      updateProbabilities(namePos);

      // String name = names[namePos];
      // System.out.println("step " + i + ": picked " + name + " (index " + namePos + ") based on " + randomValue);
      // System.out.println("new probabilities: " + Arrays.toString(probabilities));
    }

    System.out.println("Final probabilities: " + Arrays.toString(probabilities));
  }

  public int findIndex(double randomValue) {
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
      if (thresholds[i] > randomValue) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

With those intermediate console logs commented off, because you don't want to see a thousand intermediaries... unless you do, of course.

Comment: Fascinating. The original question is tagged `java` and it contains java code. Your answer contains _JavaScript_ code **and** it got up-voted. What am I missing?

Comment: yeah, noticed that too - it's a useful answer as it describes a better approach, but its in the wrong language. I'm currently rewriting it to java, since that's pretty easy.

Comment: Yeah, i just wanted to write about the JavaScript issue as well, thx for commenting about it too @Abra

Comment: Lemme clarify, i want a name to pop up every time i run the program, each time the name that just popped up before, will have a lower chance of popping up again - hence an array of 30 and 10 spot of each name, you code.. idk gave me some weird numbers? thx for trying to explain Mike, but i don't think you understood my problem. @Pomax

Comment: that is literally what this code does though. You don't need "multiple spots for each name", you just literally reduce the probability of that name getting picked next time, every time it gets picked. As long as your random number generator is fair, this does exactly what you described.

Comment: Okaayy it might've took me a day to understand what u were trying to do,
The name pops up and the the probability is changing (the three numbers) and the steps is how many time u want the program to do it. but my problem was saving the data for a run after that not 10 steps at a time, for example i run it now - get a name and a week later i get a new name with the set possibilities 
is there any way to save the data in the array? @Pomax

Comment: Not three, "one for each name". If you have 10 names you have 10 probabilities (all starting at 1/10). If you have 70 names, you have 70 probabilities (all starting at 1/70). As for "can I save the data and then a week later run it again": of course? But that has _literally nothing_ to do with your program, that's just "how do I save an array (to file/database/firebase/whatever) so I can reload it later", which is a completely different question: of course you can, you should be able to find several posts on SO on how to do that already.